# How to find function growth in this asymptotic analysis problem?

Tags: asymptotics

Let $n=m!$ Which of the following is TRUE:

$m=\Theta \left( \frac{\log n}{log \log n} \right)m=\Theta \left( \frac{\log⁡n}{\log⁡\log⁡n} \right)$

$m=\Omega \left( \frac{\log n} {\log \log n} \right)$ but not $m=O \left( \frac{\log n} {\log \log n} \right)$

$m=\Theta(\log^2 n)$ $m=\Theta(\log^2 ⁡n)$

$m=\Omega(\log^2 n)$ but not $m=Ο(\log^2 ⁡n)$

$m=\Theta(\log^{1.5} n)$

Answer (score 0):

If $n = m!$
then
$\ln n
=\ln m!
=m\ln m - m+O(\ln m)
=m\ln m(1+o(1))
$
so
$\ln \ln n
=\ln m +\ln \ln m+o(1)
=\ln m(1+o(1))
$
so
$\dfrac{\ln n}{\ln \ln n}
=m(1+o(1))
$.

Comment: so what we can conclude from the options ?

Comment: The first is true, although I don't know exactly what you mean by the second part of each option.